# Removing specific the foreign key using code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

[image]
As you can see in the image, Staff_StaffId was a foreign key created at first migration, but now I need to change it. Before I make the change, I have to make sure it is removed. I need your help!

My domain looks like

```
       public class StaffCycles
        {
         [Key]
         public Guid StaffCycleId { get; set; }


           }
```

Answer (score 0):

- By just opening the table in design mode and selecting the column I want to remove, I clicked the relationship symbol of Microsoft SQL Management studio.
- Then I deleted the relationship.
- Finally, I did the migration from the visual studio by adding the columns I want in the domain.